# Android Share link and video on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, video, facebook-android-sdk

I've followed the instruction of sharing android app on [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/)  that would be:
1. Link the SDK with Maven
2. set android app id on manifast file and provider and adding Android Key Hash to developer profile. but didn't add Facebook Activity as I found it is optional.
 codes for sharing video is:

```
File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + videoPath);
                    Uri videoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                    ShareVideo ShareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
                            .setLocalUrl(videoFileUri)
                            .build();
                    ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                            .setVideo(ShareVideo)
                            .build();
                    ShareDialog.show(ShareVideoFragment.this, content);
```

and codes for sharing link is:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(videoPath))
                                .build();
                        ShareDialog.show(ShareVideoFragment.this, content);
```

the problem is that other users(except sender) can't see the link and video that were posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was because my app was in develop mode, I should set that in Facebook develop profile to live mode.
[image]